# Alert message is wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently new to JavaScript and am learning in school! There is an assignment that I am doing by creating a game but the alert keeps popping up with the wrong one. Every time it alerts as "You found a match!" for every card, however this is not supposed to happen. I have been trying to figure this out for the last hour. Thanks

```
var cards = ["queen", "king", "queen", "king"];

var cardsInPlay = [];

var cardOne = cards[0];

cardsInPlay.push(cardOne);

console.log("User flipped " + cardOne);

var cardTwo = cards[1];

cardsInPlay.push(cardTwo);

console.log("User flipped " + cardTwo);

if (cardsInPlay.length === 2){
    cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1];
    alert("You found a match!");
} else {
        alert("Sorry, try again");
    }
```

Comment: Assuming you fix the syntax, how can cardsInPlay[0] ever be equal to cardsInPlay[1]??

Comment: @frenchie Presumably this is an intermediary step in a coding example.

Comment: @frenchie I believe the purpose of this is to only get one message, within the PreCourse work we have not completed the steps to make it a working game but presumably you could make it easier by changing the array variables `var cardOne = cards[3];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you ment to put the condition like below:

```
if (cardsInPlay.length === 2 && cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
  alert("You found a match!");
}
```

Comment: WOW, I completely over looked that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You have a simple syntax error.

```
if (cardsInPlay.length === 2){
  cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1];
```

By putting your second conditional inside the bracket `{`, you've made it ineffective.  Try this:

```
if (cardsInPly.length === 2 && cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
```

The condition always goes inside the parenthesis `(` `)`.  If it's outside of it, it won't work.

Typing `cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1];` when they aren't equal is effectively like typing `false;`.  It's technically valid, but doesn't do anything.

Comment: WOW, I completely over looked that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Worth to mention that now it will never be a match

Comment: There is no `syntax error` when writing `cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1];`  inside the `if` statement.

Comment: @TânNguyễn No compiler syntax error, no, but an error in syntax of the if statement, yes.  It's obvious what the intent of the code was, and incorrect syntax was used.  That's why I included the extra explanation.

Comment: I was looking and trying to think about what I put wrong, when really it was just my syntax in the wrong place without my &&. I guess that is what happens when you spend too much time looking into something without a break

Comment: @T.Evans I might also recommend a decent IDE, where syntax highlighting will help you catch this stuff.  :-)  For what it's worth, I often juggle many projects at once for this very reason.  It's hard to stare at the same code for awhile, but if you can switch off to something else, you think about it on a background thread and come back and see your errors.  That's difficult to do when you're still learning though.

Comment: @Brad I am using Sublime Text right now but I don't have an IDE with it, is there a plugin or extension that would work with this? Thanks

Comment: @T.Evans Sublime is fine.

Comment: @Brad Awesome! Thanks again for your help!